# Can someone please explain the "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error I keep getting?

Tags: c, syntax-error, assignment-operator

I'm new to C and starting the problems on Project Euler, can't understand the error so would appreciate any help.

```
while (i < 10)
{
    if (i % 3 = 0);
    printf("%d", i);

    if (i % 5 = 0);
    printf("%d", i);

    i++;
}
```

> "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

is the error.

Comment: Sorry should have said that the value I'm on about is the int **i**

Comment: `if (i % 3 = 0);` --> `if (i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: Why isn't there a "What's the difference between = and ==?" Q&A? That could be used to close sooo many duplicates…

Answer (score 4):

You're using `=`, which is the assignment operator, when you should be using `==`, which is the equality operator.

You're getting the error because you're attempting to assign a value to `i % 3`, which is not something you can assign to.

In C there are rvalues, which are expressions that can't be assigned to, and lvalues, which are expressions that can be assigned to.  Put another way, lvalues can appear on the left side of an assignment and rvalues may only appear on the right side.

Also, you have a `;` immediately after each of your `if` statements, meaning they have an empty body.  Get rid of those.

```
while (i < 10)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        printf("%d", i);

    if (i % 5 == 0)
        printf("%d", i);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistakes, still learning.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), your code looks like

```
if ( (i % 3) = 0);
```

Now, the `=` you've used is an assignment operator, and as per `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

OTOH, the result of a modulo operator (`%`) is not a modifiable lvalue, so you keep getting the error.

You need to change the `=` to `==`, later being the Equality operator.

That said, the `;` at the end of the `if` statement is also something you probably don't want. You need to remove the trailing `;` if you want the `printf()` statement as the `if` condition statement(body).